# Git create branch from range of previous commits?

Tags: git

I have a bunch of commits for an OS project and I want to pull out just the last say 20 commits into another branch so I can pull request.

How could I do this? The reason being is I have maybe 150 commits, but most of those are for a much larger contribute, which isn't ready yet. But the next version is being released soon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can do this with `cherry-pick`. If your history of `long_branch` looks like this:

```
A-B  <-- master
   \
    C-D-E-F-G-H  <-- long_branch
```

and you want to move the contents of, say, F through H to a different branch, say, `short_branch`, which is based off of `master`:

```
git checkout master -b short_branch
```

which gives

```
A-B  <-- master, short_branch
   \
    C-D-E-F-G-H  <-- long_branch
```

then... (note that the commit range is `E..H`; the left side is non-inclusive for the range)

```
git cherry-pick E..H
```

which gives:

```
    F'-G'-H'  <-- short_branch
   /
A-B  <-- master
   \
    C-D-E-F-G-H  <-- long_branch
```

Note that I'm referring to the new commits as `F'`, `G'`, `H'` - this is because while they will contain the same effective changes as `F`, `G`, and `H`, they won't be the actual same commits (due to different parents + commit times).

Comment: Wow I would upvote this twice if I could. A very concise, non-esoteric example that is extremely understandable and covers the gotchas. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Do you want the 20 commits to remain on the current branch?  If not, then keep a reference to the current branch back 20 commits with:

```
git checkout -b current_branch_save current_branch~20
```

Then, move the last 20 commits with rebase

```
git checkout current_branch
git rebase --onto another_branch current_branch~20 current_branch
```

Now you've got current_branch_save with your ~100 'not quite ready' commits and current_branch on another_branch with the last 20.

Comment: This really helped me in getting rid of merge conflicts. +1

Comment: Just to add to this, you can use `git rebase --onto another_branch 39ai32^ current_branch`, where `39ai32` is the hash of the earliest commit you want to keep.