# apply patch and include missing files across branches

Tags: git

I want to apply a patch and include missing files. The new files and patch originate from a branch and want to apply it to my master branch. I'm looking for a one liner, if it exists. I guess I want to merge missing files that are mentioned in patch.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you'd like to merge a branch which has the necessary changes that you expect to a master branch. If that is right, then

checkout master

```
git checkout master
```

merge the branch which has your changes to the master

```
git merge branch_name
```

If I've mistaken your question, and what you have is only a set of patches like
000x-feature-y.patch, then checkout master, then apply all the patches to it like this

```
git am /path/to/the/patches/dir/*.patch
```

If the above doesn't answer your question, please try to make your question clear!

HTH

Comment: I only want to patch files from branches latest commit. Will a git merge, merge all updated files.

Comment: Refer here[1] for a detailed example of merging.
[1] http://www.quora.com/Git-revision-control/How-does-git-merge-work

Answer (score 0):

You can cherry-pick them:

- http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/06/git-tip-of-week-cherry-picking.html
- [Git create branch from range of previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853681/git-create-branch-from-range-of-previous-commits)